# perl grabbing text between two keywords

Tags: perl

I am trying to read in the text between two keywords. Not really working though. All I want is to read in the question and answer and then have it print out. It does not work, just keeps on printing out a really big loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings;
my $question ;
my $answer ;

while(my $line = <>){
chomp $line ;

if ($line =~ /questionstart(.*)questionend/) {
    $question = $1 ; }
elsif ($line  =~ /answerstart(.*)answerend/) {
    $answer = $1 ; }

my $flashblock = <<"FLASH" ;
<!-- BEGIN -->
<p class="question">
  $question
</p>
<p class="answer">
   $answer
</p>
<!-- END -->
FLASH
print $flashblock ;
}
```

This is a sample of the file

```
questionstart

hellphellohellohello


questionend

answerstart

hellohellohello

answerend
```

Comment: no this is different - there is something going on with the while loop and I don wane to include the start text - just what is in between the key words

Comment: Are there multiple question/answer blocks in your text file? Do you want a flash block printed for each one?

Comment: for the file shown, it prints a bunch of block - I just want one.

Comment: Thanks--I understand that, but is your file only one question and answer as shown, or are there multiple questions and answers?

Comment: one question one answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, a multi-line regex is never going to work when you're reading your input file a line at a time.

This is a perfect use for Perl "flip/flop" operator (`..`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($question, $answer);

while (<DATA>) {
  if (/questionstart/ .. /questionend/ and ! /question(start|end)/) {
    $question .= $_;
  }

  if (/answerstart/ .. /answerend/ and ! /answer(start|end)/) {
    $answer .= $_;
  }

  # If we're at the end of an answer, do all the stuff
  if (/answerend/) {
    q_and_a($question, $answer);

    # reset text variables
    $question = $answer = '';
  }
}

sub q_and_a {
  my ($q, $a) = @_;

  print <<"FLASH";
<!-- BEGIN -->
<p class="question">
  $question
</p>
<p class="answer">
   $answer
</p>
<!-- END -->
FLASH
}

__DATA__
questionstart

hellphellohellohello


questionend

answerstart

hellohellohello

answerend
```

**Update:** Moved the display into a subroutine to make the main loop cleaner.

Comment: The other answer are great - but this one seems the easiest.

Answer (score 3):

Since the file is read line by line the sought phrase, that spans multiple lines, can never matched.

One basic approach to resolve this is to have flags for question and answer regions. Since you have very clear markers for entering and leaving these regions the code is really simple

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my ($question, $answer);
my ($in_Q, $in_A);

while (my $line = <>) {
    next if $line =~ /^\s*$/;

    if    ($line =~ /^\s*questionstart/) { $in_Q = 1; next }   
    elsif ($line =~ /^\s*questionend/)   { $in_Q = 0; next }   
    elsif ($line =~ /^\s*answerstart/)   { $in_A = 1; next }   
    elsif ($line =~ /^\s*answerend/)     { $in_A = 0; next }       

    if    ($in_Q) { $question .= $line }
    elsif ($in_A) { $answer   .= $line }
}

say "Question: $question";
say "Answer: $answer";
```

(I condensed `if-elsif` statements only for brevity and emphasis here)

This code makes some reasonable assumptions about the input file. I require the markers to start the line (with possible spaces), but allow for more text following them.  If you want to make sure that they are the only thing on the line add the `$` anchor at the end of regex (again with `\s*`).

It is stated that input has one Q/A. If it ever changes to multiple ones then move the prints inside the loop, once the answer-end comes so under `elsif (/^\s*answerend/) { .. }`

The printing in the question is fine so I don't repeat it here. If there is ever a chance to print format other than HTML, then clean up the resulting strings from leading and trailing spaces, multiple spaces, and newlines.

---

The repeated tests on the same variable may lead one to seek a case-type construct, what in Perl would be [switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements). However, that is still an experimental feature, which operates in a way which

> is hard to describe precisely

(documentation!).  Further, it may also get *smart matching* involved, which is plain hard to describe, widely understood to be broken in its current form, and certain to be changed. So I recommend to stick with cascading if-elsif statements (in this approach).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach involves reading the file line by line, but your regex is attempting to grab multiple lines between a question/answer's start and end. No lines in your file will match such a multiline regex and you'll ultimately wind up with uninitialized `$question` and `$answer` variables and a block/warning printed for each line in your file.

It makes sense to read the whole text file into a string, then split it on question/answer blocks and trim contents (if desired):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die "Can't open file $!";
my @qa = grep(/\w+/g, split /^(questionstart|answerstart|questionend|answerend)$/mg, do {local $/; <$fh>});
s/^\s+|\s+$//g foreach @qa;

my $flashblock = << "FLASH";
<!-- BEGIN -->
<p class="question">
    $qa[0]
</p>
<p class="answer">
    $qa[1]
</p>
<!-- END -->
FLASH

print $flashblock;
```

Output:

```
<!-- BEGIN -->
<p class="question">
    hellphellohellohello
</p>
<p class="answer">
    hellohellohello
</p>
<!-- END -->
```

If you have multiple question/answer pairs in one file, you can loop over the `@qa` array and print pairs or put them into a hash and use as desired.